# check a form to see if nothing has changed

Tags: jquery

In the app I'm working on, the first thing a user needs to do after authenticating is to enter a name in an input form and save it.

If the user tries to leave the form without having entered something and saved it, I would like to be able to detect this behavior and prevent it, possibly with an alert that reminds them they must first save the form (and not give them a choice).

I know how to use jquery .change() to check if the contents of an input box have changed, but I don't know how to check to see if nothing has changed.

Comment: Why not use a normal validation routine?

Comment: I'm a jquery rookie and currently do all of my form validation in django, so I'm not aware of how to use normal validation to accomplish what I'm after (checking to see if nothing has been entered in an input form).

Comment: Check jquery validate plugin. But see below, validation need to be done against initial value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the initial state of each input element and then test for it.

I've written a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/Rq6hC/) that does that for checkboxes, but you'll get the point.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful example.  I notice that for the checkboxes in the example, you're evaluating whether or not the box is checked.  Is there a comparable parameter for text input boxes that would indicate if they are empty?

Comment: Instead of `$(this).is(':checked')` you can use `$(this).val()` to get whatever is in the textbox